# What does the program cclive do?

Tags: command-line

I run:

```
$ cclive "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfLTl1yBzpg"
```

and receive this error message:

```
Checking ... ........ libquvi: error: /usr/share/quvi/lua/website/youtube.lua:117: no match: fmt_url_map
```

I run:

```
$ cclive "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uuFeQXyODA"
```

and receive this error message:

```
Checking ... ....... libquvi: error: /usr/share/quvi/lua/website/youtube.lua:117: no match: fmt_url_map
```

Etc., etc., etc.

Comment: The simplest usage example: `$ cclive "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUM1284TqFc"` does not work.

Comment: That specific usage worked for a user testing in chat.

Comment: That specific usage does not work for users testing in here.

Comment: the bug you're referencing has to do with mismatched library versions apparently: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cclive/+bug/874554 ... voting to close as a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

From http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cclive/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions:

> Cclive is a command line tool for downloading videos from Youtube and other similar video websites that require Adobe Flash to view the video content. It has low memory footprint compared to other similar tools. It is a rewrite of clive.

[image]
It works for at least one AskUbuntu user.

The reason for your troubles is due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cclive/+bug/874554), but with the wording of the question, that is beside the point.